# How to fix spaces in bootstrap justified text columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, multiple-columns

I'm creating a div that needs to have two columns, each one with justified alignment. Problem is: it looks good when I use two divs bootstrap `col-lg6-` , but when it comes to `col-md-6`, `col-sm-6`, it results in a lot of spaces between words in order to maintain the justified alignment when dealing with different sized words.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/unaSS.jpg [link for image samples]

1) I've already tried using pure CSS:

```
#third-div{
background-color: #904e45;
text-align: justify;
column-count:2;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
column-gap: 40px;
}
```

2) tried to use `word-break: break-all;`
but ofc this breaks the words with no grammatical logic.

3) Now I'm trying to use two Bootstrap cols inside a bootstrap row, like:

```
<div id="third-div" class="page-div">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <h1>Lots of text</h1>
          <h2 class="fio">But divided: two columns</h2>
          <p> a lot of text here  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <p> a lot of text here </p>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
```

```
.page-div{
  padding: 15%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#third-div{
  background-color: #904e45;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way as text-align: justify works. It appends equal space between words to keep the text justified, if you fix it it wouldn't be justified anymore.

I think the solution is keeping one column on a small screen

```
<div id="third-div" class="page-div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h1>Lots of text</h1>
          <h2 class="fio">But divided: two columns</h2>
          <p> a lot of text here  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <p> a lot of text here </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way they should go under each other like a single column and there would be enough space to optimize the justifying the text.

Comment: Hmmm thank you! I was looking for a way to keep the two columns and let the text justified but w/o the spacing, even if I had to remove `text-align` and use something else, but I guess I'll do what you said and put them in a single column, then. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers (FireFox) you can set the justification the spacing to use *letter* spacing (acts similar to adjusting kerning in software like In-Design) instead of the default *word* spacing. I think it looks better for some text in narrow columns. 
See [CSS-tricks' Text-Justify](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-justify/) 
[image]